# How to pass python data back to the calling script about a browser window left open when the called script closes

Tags: python, json, selenium, pickle

I am trying to find the best method to pass data from python script2.py back to the calling script (script1.py). I am using Python 3 on Linux.

Script1 calls script2.py which then uses Selenium to open a browser window and do something things. When script2 ends, the browser remains open and script1 continues. What I want is to then be able to work on the browser window that was opened in script2, from within script1.

So far I have failed to find a suitable way to pass the information about the open browser window from script2 back to script1. I believe part of the issue is because when script2 is called, script1 waits until it has closed before continuing on, so there is no way to grab the variables open in script2. I do not want to change this aspect either.

in script1.py the below code calls script2 like this:

```
cmd = ['python3', '/home/admin/Desktop/Python_stuff/live-scripts/script2.py']
        subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait() # Python will now wait for script to end before continuing
```

in script2 the below code opens the browser initially (which currently stays open after script2 closes) like this:

```
driver.get(targetURL)
```

I have looked at Pickle but could not get it to work how I wanted and will probably next try to use import JSON. But I wondered if I am missing a more simple method to achieve what I want here.

Comment: More simple is to use selenium in the main script. What's the point of subprocess here?

Comment: @pguardiario I think merging the scripts might be the best way to address it but it will require re-designing the entire process just to pass a variable. Regardless of that, I think it important for me to learn the principle of how to achieve this simple transfer of data between scripts, in case it is required in a future project.

Comment: It's more useful to learn how to make a module, using subprocess for this is bad design.

Comment: are you certain of that? what about if script2 needed to remain seperate and be called by script1. or script3, or many other scripts. maybe that is what you mean by module, but could you explain that if so. I am learning python, not an expert in it.

Comment: It's too much to get into here, but you should look for some tutorials.

Comment: I will do that thanks for the tip. probably explains why searching for a solution my way was proving fruitless on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pguardiario in the comments for setting me on the right track. The answer to this is to use script2 as a module.

I had actually tried to do this already, but it was crashing my script1 because I had dashes in the naming of my scripts, which works fine when they are scripts, but for some reason does not work when they are used as modules and yet gives you no error either. It just bombs out of the script altogether (on my linux/python 3 setup this is the case).

The solution was surprisingly simple once I resolved the file naming issues.

in script1.py I now have

```
import script2
```

then I call the main() function from the second script with

```
script2.main
```

I did not have to make any changes to script2, it runs from the local folder so needs no additional path setting, and I can now remove all the script calling code as well.

The main point being don't use dashes in the naming of modules as it gives you no error warnings but wont import them.